# Changing the data of the repeater in wix

Tags: javascript, jquery, velo

I'm trying to manipulate the repeater list in Wix. When the user selects the quantity of equipment, that number of forms show up. I got the hang of it when I see it in the console log but when I try to display it on the web, it gives me an error. I've tried reassigning $w("#repeater1").data to newArr(the new data).

Here's my code

```
$w("#repeater1").hide();
    let itemOptions = $w("#quoteDropdown").options

    $w("#quoteDropdown").onChange((event) => {  
        $w("#repeater1").show();

        const arrOfValues = []
        let newArr = []
        let repeaterData = $w("#repeater1").data;    
        let quantity = Number(event.target.value);

        let iterator = repeaterData.values();
        for(const value of iterator) {
            arrOfValues.push(value);
        }

        for(let i = 0 ; i < itemOptions.length; i++) { 
            newArr = repeaterData.slice(0, quantity);
        }        

        if(quantity > newArr.length) {
            let newItems = arrOfValues.filter(arr => {
                newArr.forEach(na => arr !== na)
            })
            newArr.push(newItems)
        }
        console.log("newArr");
        console.log(newArr);

         // $w("#repeater1").data is the original data from the repeater
         // newArr is the altered data from the repeater based on how it appears based on the users' interaction.
         
         // I've tried each one of these
         // $w("#repeater1").data = newArr;
        // return newArr;
 
    }); // end onChange
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to assign the array as the data for a repeater, you need to follow some rules. First, it needs to be an array of objects. Second, each object needs to have an `_id` property.